# How to do this Query (String combination)

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the data which look like this

```
Day  Month Time 
11    02   12:11:11
12    02   10:10:20
13    02   9:12:6
14    02   6:7:2
```

as you can see the data in Time Column is not Timestamp but String, therefore some of The Data has the wrong Format like this: 9:12:6 not 09:12:06.
what i want to do now is a new Colum which combine String of Day, Month, and correct Time Format, the ":" need to be removed. 
The Result should looks like this:

```
new Colum
1102121111
1202101020
1302091206
1402060702
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks

---

```
CREATE TABLE Saletime (
day VARCHAR(02) NOT NULL,
month VARCHAR(02) NOT NULL,
time VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO saletime(day, month, time) VALUES ('11','02','12:11:11');
INSERT INTO saletime(day, month, time) VALUES ('12','02','10:10:20');
INSERT INTO saletime(day, month, time) VALUES ('13','02','9:12:6');
INSERT INTO saletime(day, month, time) VALUES ('14','02','6:7:2');
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please tag it accordingly. So you just want the three columns concatenated without special characters?

Comment: Sorry, we use oracle DB, i just want to concatenatethem without special charater

Comment: But you also need the leading 0s correct?

Comment: yes kchason, i need 0 for incorrect format

Comment: Is it possible to make `saletime` a timestamp column and use `TO_CHAR(saletime,"DDMMHHMISS")` to achieve the same results?

Comment: what i need is just the string like this: 1102121111. i have tried some code but it doesnt work

Comment: If you use Oracle, why isn't there Oracle tag??????

Comment: How are PM hours stored? There is no AM or PM in your sample strings; so perhaps they use 24 hour format (15:30:00 for 3:30 PM?)

Comment: Also: please note that strings in Oracle are enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes. I will edit your post to fix that. Oh - and... ugh, you can't insert more than one row at a time that way. I will fix that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the inputs and the output are all strings, perhaps direct string manipulation makes sense. (It would be **much** better if the output were `date` data type, but that is in your hands, not in mine.)

I follow your lead in using *day* and *month* as column names. That is a very poor practice; I hope your actual column names are different.

It's not clear if you may need the same left-padding with 0 for the day and month; just in case, I handled it too (it's done the same way).

```
select day, month, time,
       lpad(day, 2, '0') || lpad(month, 2, '0')
       || lpad(regexp_substr(time, '\d+', 1, 1), 2, '0')
       || lpad(regexp_substr(time, '\d+', 1, 2), 2, '0')
       || lpad(regexp_substr(time, '\d+', 1, 3), 2, '0') as new_string
from   saletime;

DATE  MONTH  TIME       NEW_STRING
----  -----  ---------  ----------
  11     02  12:11:11   1102121111
  12     02  10:10:20   1202101020
  13     02  9:12:6     1302091206
  14     02  6:7:2      1402060702
```

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the values then parse them

```
select to_char(
  to_timestamp(
  day||'-'||month||' '||time,
  'DD-MM HH24:MI:SS'),
  'DDMMHHMISS') 
from Saletime;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/897a5a/1/0)

Comment: Exactly as written, `to_timestamp` will fail if, as I suspect, the OP's inputs are in 24-hour format. Same with `to_date` (I don't understand why you need `to_timestamp` but using it here is just strange, it is not incorrect).

Comment: Also, if you enclose table and column names within double-quotes like that, the query will fail in Oracle Database; do not use double quoted names unless they were defined in double quotes. (In this case they weren't!)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this as a numeric calculation:

```
select (day * 100000000 +
        month * 1000000 +
        cast(regexp_substr(time, '[0-9]+', 1, 1) as number) * 10000 +
        cast(regexp_substr(time, '[0-9]+', 1, 2) as number) * 100 +
        cast(regexp_substr(time, '[0-9]+', 1, 3) as number) * 1
       )
 from saletime;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09afb/6) is a SQL Fiddle.

If you want this as a string, just convert it to a string.

Comment: While at the same time a wrong solution is upvoted...   Beats me!

Comment: Although... Your answer produces a number; the original question suggests, and then the OP states explicitly in a Comment, that the desired result is a string. Especially if the day is between 1 and 9, one may guess that the OP wants the leading 0. So your answer would have to be cast to string, with a format mask that guarantees the leading 0 (when needed).

Comment: @mathguy . . . Where in the question does it say that the result should be a string?  "what i want to do now is a new Colum which combine String of Day, Month, and correct Time Format, the ":" need to be removed. The Result should looks like this:"  Nothing indicates that the result is a string -- although casting the numeric value to a string is easy enough.

Comment: Combining three strings... **The : needs to be removed** - that makes sense only if the result is a string; it makes no sense if the result is a date (a date is neither "with" or "without" colons, as you know) - although this is giving the OP a lot of credit. But that suspicion is then clearly confirmed in a Comment, posted - it seems - one hour before your Answer, give or take.

Comment: Not sure who did, or why. Like you, I doubt strongly that it was the OP. One of the drive-by dunces the site is full of. (You know, those who downvote and don't give a reason.) By the way - of course - the downvote is not from me; I always explain my downvotes. Sometimes I am wrong, but that's another matter.